# How to read plain text from .doc and .docx document and display in Flex3 text area

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, file-io, flex3

We are in the process of developing a CRM application and for that we need to upload *.doc and *.docx files and display that contents.

We successfully uploaded the *.doc and *.docx files in application by using FileReference and FileReferenceList. Would you please tell me some idea to read the contents from *.doc and *.docx files and to display the uploaded file content into flex text area.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://ntt.cc/2010/03/28/how-to-open-word-doc-in-flex-or-actionscript.html) shows one way to open a doc or docx through flash, but it will not output the text into a flex text area. In order to do that, you're going to have to decode the word file, which is not an easy task. I know of an as3 [library for opening excel documents](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/), which can give you an idea as to what you'll have to do, but I'm not aware of an existing library that will read word files for you.